# Android. Picasso и Adapter. Не отображаются картинки

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, picasso

Есть адаптер:

```
public class ListPlantsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<ListPlants> objects;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Picasso mPicasso;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ListPlantsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListPlants> listPlants){
        ctx = context;
        objects = listPlants;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mPicasso = Picasso.with(context);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return objects.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = contentView;
        if (view == contentView){
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_cards_list_view, parent, false);
        }
        ListPlants l = getListPlants(position);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.namePlant)).setText(l.name);
        ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageURI(Uri.parse(l.image));
        mPicasso.load("/storage/72AD-2013/Download/46298-red-batman-logo-2880x1800-comic-wallpaper.jpg").into((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2));
        return view;
    }
    ListPlants getListPlants(int position){
        return ((ListPlants)getItem(position));
    }
}
```

конструктор:

```
public class ListPlants {
    String name;
    String image;
    ListPlants(String _name, String _image){
        name = _name;
        image = _image;
    }
}
```

Если закомментировать
 `mPicasso.load("/storage/72AD-2013/Download/46298-red-batman-logo-2880x1800-comic-wallpaper.jpg").into((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2));` 
или `mPicasso.load(l.image).into((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView2));`то будет работать мой адаптер и листВью. Хочу, что бы картинки кэшировались и лист не лагал. Как только добавляю строчку с пикасо - картинки не отображаются вообще.
 Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо добавить схему к вашему Uri картинки. В случае ссылок в интернет схема - `http`, а у вас локальный файл, значит надо добавить `"file://"`, т.е.

```
mPicasso.load("file://" + "/storage/72AD-2013/Download/46298-red-batman-logo-2880x1800-comic-wallpaper.jpg")
```

Comment: спасибо, странно, что нигде наткнулся на file:// сам